# Rails GridView gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to find a gem that gives me the ability of advanced Grid View.
Something like here: http://demo.activeadmin.info/admin/orders

It can paginate, sort and search/filter. Do you know some gems?

I saw https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails but it can't search by each field separately. For example: `title = 'Test'` and `type = 'post'`. This image can help you understand what I want. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAevP.png

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the [Gem](https://github.com/Nerian/FooTable-rails) yet, but [FooTable](http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/) works pretty cool and has helped us out in a pinch. Of course, you would have to build the table yourself, but shouldn't be too difficult.